# Yocto - Out-of-tree modules not re-built after changing kernel

Tags: linux, module, yocto, bitbake

I am experiencing an issue where after I re-configure and re-build the kernel, my out-of-tree modules are not automatically recompiled the next time I build my image. There seems to be an issue with the make-mod-scripts/module.bbclass dependency chain based on my observations:

The behavior I expect:

When I do **bitbake -c cleanall make-mod-scripts** then all of my out-of-tree modules should be re-compile next the their recipes are run, since modules.bbclass contains **do_configure[depends] += "make-mod-scripts:do_compile"**

The behavior I observe:

When I run **bitbake -c cleanall make-mod-scripts && bitbake hello-world** (where hello-world is my out-of-tree module), hello-world is not re-built. The hello-world recipe will cause make-mod-scripts to re-build, but none of the tasks for hello-world are re-run, so the module is not re-compiled.

I am using Yocto 4.0 (kirkstone)

Thank you for your help!